# NP-hardness proof of an optimization problem with real values and real input in the decision problem

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-hard, proof-techniques, decision-problem

**Question** - Let's suppose we have an optimization problem $\mathcal{P}$ with a real-valued measure function and the decision version of the optimization problem $\mathcal{P}_D$ (please see definitions below). Let's say we have a reduction from an $NP$-complete problem to a decision problem $\mathcal{P}_D'$ with $W \in \mathbb{R}$, where $W$ is of the form $f(w^p), w \in \mathbb{Q}, p \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, and $f(.)$ is a simple algebraic function. Finally, let's say $\mathcal{P}_D$ contains $\mathcal{P}_D'$. Can we conclude an $NP$-hardness result for $\mathcal{P}$ here in any way?

I've found this [NP-hardness of an optimization problem with real value](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/np-hardness-of-an-optimization-problem-with-real-value) related question. In case of $\mathcal{P}_D'$ and for a fixed $p$ the value of $W$ comes from a countable set so I think the $NP$-hardness follows but I'm not sure I understood everything correctly.

Also, Manyem (2013) uses an $NP$-optimization problem definition, where the measure function takes values in $\mathbb{R}_0^{+}$. He notes that "when it comes to computer representation, rational numbers will be used". At the same time he defines the decision version of the optimization problem, which also uses a constant $W \in \mathbb{R}_0^{+}.$ So I wonder whether a precise argument for $NP$-hardness could be made using this computer representation too. Any reference is much appreciated.

--- Key definitions from Ausiello et al. (2003) ---

**Definition 1** - An optimization problem $\mathcal{P}$ is characterized by the following quadruple of objects $(I_{\mathcal{P}}, {SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}, m_{\mathcal{P}}, {goal}_{\mathcal{P}})$, where:

1. $I_{\mathcal{P}}$ is the set of instances of $\mathcal{P}$;
2. ${SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}$ is a function that associates to any input instance $x \in I_{\mathcal{P}}$ the set of feasible solutions of $x$;
3. $m_{\mathcal{P}}$ is the measure function, defined for pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \in I_{\mathcal{P}}$ and $y \in {SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}(x)$. For every such pair $(x,y)$, $m_{\mathcal{P}}$ provides a positive integer which is the value of the feasible solution $y$;
4. ${goal}_{\mathcal{P}} \in \{ \min, \max \}$ specifies whether $\mathcal{P}$ is a maximization or a minimization problem.

Ausiello et al. (2003) makes a note at point 3 that in practice for several problems the measure function is defined to have values in $\mathbb{Q}$, and that it is equivalent with the above one.
Denote the value of an optimal solution of $x$ by $m^{*}(x)$. Then the corresponding decision problem to $\mathcal{P}$ is the following:

**Decision Problem** ($\mathcal{P}_D$) - Given an instance $x \in I$ and a positive integer $W \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, decide whether $m^{*}(x) \geq W$ (if goal $= \max$) or whether $m^{*}(x) \leq W$ (if goal $= \min$). If goal $= \max$, the set $\{ (x,W) | x 
\in I \wedge m^{*}(x) \geq W \}$ (or $\{ (x,W) | x 
\in I \wedge m^{*}(x) \leq W \}$ if goal $= \min$) is called the *underlying language* of $\mathcal{P}$.

Based on the above note I assume when the measure function is defined to have values in $\mathbb{Q}$ then the variable $W$ may also have values in $\mathbb{Q}$ in the above definition.

**Definition 2** - An optimization problem $\mathcal{P}$ is called $NP$-hard if, for every decision problem $\mathcal{P}' \in NP, \mathcal{P}' \leq_{T}^{p} \mathcal{P}$, that is, $\mathcal{P}'$ can be solved in polynomial time by an algorithm which uses an oracle that, for any instance $x \in I_{\mathcal{P}}$, returns an optimal solution $y^{*}(x)$ of $x$ along with its value $m^{*}_{\mathcal{P}} (x)$.

References:

Ausiello, G., Crescenzi, P., Gambosi, G., Kann, V., Marchetti-Spaccamela, A. and Protasi, M. (2003). Complexity and approximation: Combinatorial optimization problems andtheir approximability properties. Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 1999. DOI: [10.1007/978-3-642-58412-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-58412-1).

Manyem, P. (2013). Syntactic expressions to express NP-hard optimization problems and problems with zero duality gap. A Journal of Mathematical Programming and Operations Research. 62(9):1227-1246. DOI: [10.1080/02331934.2011.625027](https://doi.org/10.1080/02331934.2011.625027).